# Why does this pointer to pointer two dimensional array assign new int like this

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im struggling to understand something with this code:

```
int **p_p_tictactoe;
p_p_tictactoe = new int*[ 3 ];
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
p_p_tictactoe[ i ] = new int[ 3 ];
}
```

on the line: `p_p_tictactoe[i] = new int [3];` The square brackets dereference p_p_tictactoe once so that we are looking at the value at the address stored by p_p_ticatactoe which is another address as it is a pointer to a pointer. Then this address is assigned to a new int but shouldn't this be assigned to the value at the address rather than the address itself like this: `*p_p_tictactoe[i] = new int[3]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *the square brackets dereference `p_p_tictactoe` once*, because they **don't**. Apart from that, what is your question? `new int* [3]` means you are creating an array of `int*` (`int` pointers), which is equal to a pointer on an `int*`, e.g. `int**` as you have written in the first line.

Comment: @Betha Uganda You could just write int ( *p_p_tictactoe )[3] = new int[3][3];

Answer (score 2):

`p_p_tictactoe` is an `int **`.

Therefore, `p_p_tictactoe[i]` must be an `int *`.

Therefore, `*p_p_tictactoe[i]` must be a single, lonely, `int`.

Assigning the result of `new`, which would be an `int *` here, to an `int` will not have any useful results.

Another helpful way of looking at this: `*p_p_tictactoe[i]` is equivalent to `p_p_tictactoe[i][0]`. That, obviously, is an `int`, a single cell, and stuffing a pointer into it, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`*p_p_tictactoe[i]` (also spelt `p_p_tictactoe[i][0]`) will be one of the `int`s in the array that you're creating on that line.

As an aside, this is a very inefficient memory layout. Unless your array is likely to change dimensions, or is jagged, prefer a single block of `int`s with 2D indexing faked on top.